# duplicate subscription identifier STOMP

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

When I want to send a request to one of my topics over Websocket it did not give me an access, and this is the error.

```
Received ERROR {message=[Duplicated subscription identifier], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[77]} session=18014b58-2b0e-3986-2090-f45f9f3afbb5, user=behnam text/plain payload=A subscription identified by 'Q_/topic/channelAdmins.2648.65' already exists.
```

My application is a Spring Websocket messenger which works with STOMP.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It would appear that your application is creating a subscription and not *just* sending messages. You should look for anything in your application which is creating this subscription.

Comment: tnx,but I think that i need the subscriptionID which STOMP send it by header,do u know how I cant get that?

Comment: Can you show a sample application ?